# Биндинг ObservableCollection<T> и переназначение

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml

В коде окна есть:

```
public ObservableCollection<ParkingPlace> ParkingPlaces = new ObservableCollection<ParkingPlace>();

public MainWindow()
{
DataContext = ParkingPlaces;
...
```

в разметке:

```
<StackPanel Visibility="{Binding Count, Converter={StaticResource IntToVisibilityConverter}, Mode=OneWay }">
```

Конвертер работает верно. При добавлении и удалении элементов все происходит как надо (элемент появляется/исчезает).

Вся проблема начинается после десериализации этой коллекции (переназначения?)

```
XmlSerializer xs = new XmlSerializer(typeof(ObservableCollection<ParkingPlace>));
using (StreamReader rd = new StreamReader("data.xml"))
{
    ParkingPlaces = (ObservableCollection<ParkingPlace>) xs.Deserialize(rd);
}
```

Биндинг совершенно перестает работать.
Также пробовал вариант с NotifyPropertyChanged, безрезультатно.

Comment: а если после загрузки из файла опять задать `DataContext = ParkingPlaces;`?

Comment: @MaximK работает! Но в чем проблема? Хотелось бы отметить как ответ.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Чтобы работало обновление при пересвоении - надо реализовывать INotifyPropertyChanged для контекста. Либо менять DataContext каждый раз отдельно:

```
ParkingPlaces = (ObservableCollection<ParkingPlace>) xs.Deserialize(rd);
DataContext = ParkingPlaces;
```

Comment: Под контекстом имеется ввиду MainWindow? Вариант со сменой DataContext работает.

Comment: @ionmike обычно контекст окна не ограничен одной коллекцией. В вашем случае пока можно не заморачиваться.

Comment: почитал поподробней, попозже попробую вариант с INotifyPropertyChanged, если не будет успехов, оставлю как есть. Спасибо за ответ!